# Outermost electronic configuration of f block elements

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends, periodic-table

Why is it $(n-2)\mathrm{f}^{1-14}(n-1)\mathrm{d}^{0-1}n\mathrm{s}^2$.

The only exception I thought to this formula was Thorium $\ce{5f^{0} 6d^{2} 7s^{2}}$.

So I feel it should be $(n-2)\mathrm{f}^{1-14}(n-1)\mathrm{d}^{0-2}n\mathrm{s}^2$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, if you look at the electron configurations of [Lanthanides](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Inorganic_Chemistry/Descriptive_Chemistry/f-Block_Elements/The_Lanthanides#Electron_Configuration) and [Actinides](http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Inorganic_Chemistry/Descriptive_Chemistry/f-Block_Elements/The_Actinides#Actinide_Properties_Table), Thorium seems to be the only exception from this empirical rule. You could expand the rule to also include the case of Thorium but I would say it is more useful to have the rule describe the majority of cases and remember $\ce{Th}$ as an exception.